# Testdirven.io fastApi course: error in the first stages

Tags: python, fastapi, testdriven.io

I am in the first part of TDD fastapi, docker and pytest course. I got a strange issue, that I need your help with.

When I created the first test that used torotoise it works fine, adds the record to the DB, and gets it from fastapi with no issue.

The minute I add another test (the one that adds, then reads the record), I get this error:

```
tortoise.exceptions.OperationalError: relation "textsummery" does not exist
```

(please ignore the typo in the word summary, it started as a mistake, but I use it as a way to force myself to not mindlessly copy paste everything)

If I remove the first test, this error is now gone, and the test goes without a hitch

Any reason why it won't just use the tables already created? I'm kinda at a loss on this one.

Code:

```
# C:\src\tdd-fastapi\project\test\conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app_with_db():
    # set up
    app = create_applications()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override

    register_tortoise(
        app,
        db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_TEST_URL"),
        modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
        generate_schemas=True,
        add_exception_handlers=True,
    )
```

And

```
# C:\src\tdd-fastapi\project\test\test_summeries.py
def test_create_summery(test_app_with_db):
    response = test_app_with_db.post("/summeries/", data=json.dumps({"url": "https://foo.bar"}))

    assert response.status_code == 201
    assert response.json()["url"] == "https://foo.bar"
    assert response.json()["id"] != 0

# ...

def test_read_summery(test_app_with_db):
    response = test_app_with_db.post("/summeries/", data=json.dumps({"url": "https://foo.bar"}))

    assert response.status_code == 201
    assert response.json()["url"] == "https://foo.bar"
    assert response.json()["id"] != 0

    summery_id = response.json()["id"]

    response = test_app_with_db.get(f"/summeries/{summery_id}/")
    assert response.status_code == 200

    response_dict = response.json()
    assert response_dict["id"] == summery_id
    assert response_dict["url"] == "https://foo.bar"
    assert response_dict["summery"]
    assert response_dict["created_at"]
```

*Per a comment suggestion, I added torotoise and testconf*

from tortoise import fields, models
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator

```
# C:\src\tdd-fastapi\project\app\models\tortoise.py
class TextSummery(models.Model):
    url = fields.TextField()
    summery = fields.TextField()
    created_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

SummerySchema = pydantic_model_creator(TextSummery)
```

And

```
# C:\src\tdd-fastapi\project\test\conftest.py
import os

import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from app.main import create_applications
from app.config import get_settings, Settings
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise


def get_settings_override() -> Settings:
    return Settings(testing=1, database_url=os.environ.get('DATABASE_TEST_URL'))

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def test_app():
    # setup
    app = create_applications()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override

    with TestClient(app) as test_client:

        yield test_client

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app_with_db():
    # set up
    app = create_applications()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override

    register_tortoise(
        app,
        db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_TEST_URL"),
        modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
        generate_schemas=True,
        add_exception_handlers=True,
    )

    with TestClient(app) as test_client:

        # testing
        yield test_client

    # tear down
```

Comment: I did this tutorial a few weeks ago without any troubles. Nobody is going to be able to help you with what you posted. At the very least, you should post `tortoise.py` under models. Did you also make sure to run all the migrations?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added both testconf and tortoise to the question. As for running migrations, I didn't, but the test configuration has "generate_schemas=True", so I think this only applies to the production settings. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
The problem wasn't in any of the files I included, but in main.py

Inside the create application I had this code:

```
def create_applications() -> FastAPI:
    application = FastAPI()
    register_tortoise(
        application,
        db_url = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"), 
        modules = {"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
        generate_schemas=False,  # updated
        add_exception_handlers = True
    )

    application.include_router(ping.router)
    application.include_router(summeries.router, prefix="/summeries", tags=['summeries'])

    return application
```

This was in a previous part of the course, and I forgot to remove it.
I'm not sure why it affected only the 2nd test, but I had a function that should have handled it, called init_db. After removing register_tortoise, all tests work as expected.